# Change col-lg-3 size

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-grid

I need my col-lg to have a different size depending on the resolution, for example:

How can this be done?

```
.col-lg-3 {
    /* styles for 1366x768px screen */
}
@media screen and (min-width: 1920px) and (min-height: 1080px) {
    .col-lg-3 {
        /* styles for screens larger than or equal to 1920px by 1080px */
    }
}
```

Comment: Which version of Bootstrap are you using?

Comment: My bootstrap version is 3

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend looking at the Bootstrap Grid System as this will help you gain a better understanding of how the `col` works for various screen sizes.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#grid-options

Comment: I read it, it was not enlightening to the point of solving my problem

Comment: Another option would be this Bootstrap 3 tutorial on adding an '-xl' breakpoint: https://spin.atomicobject.com/2015/03/06/bootstrap-add-xl-grid-size-option/